# Windows Phone 8.1 does not allow file transfer when internet sharing mode

Tags: 8.1, wifi, internet-sharing, file-transfer

I just want to know why Windows Phone 8.1 does not allow file transfer when internet sharing mode but allows when WiFi mode. In android file transfer is allowed in both the modes (using ShareIt, Zapya, etc.)

We can share files WP to Android, Android to WP but WP to WP is not possible unless both WPs are connected to same WiFi. Whats the reason?

Comment: Are you using any apps to share files? Please list them.

Comment: looks like you are talking about shareit.....There is a better way to share data using `easy transfer`

Comment: How are you sharing? via Bluetooth? Are you using an app?

Comment: Yes @Mohammedaadhil I'm talking apps like shareit. I'm not able to transfer WP to WP since one of them will have to enable internet sharing mode.

Comment: @A.B. shareit doesnot allow that feature yet (May b because they are still trying for a workaround to nullify wp's restriction)......There are other apps like `easy transfer` that allows you to send from wp to wp(even with hotspot)

Comment: Yeah right @Mohammedaadhil. I just installed `easy transfer`. And it works even in Hotspot Mode. Its too good.
`ShareIt` on WP is not official I think because some days ago it's name had changed to `ShareIt Unofficial` and again changed it back to `ShareIt' in next update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [Easy Transfer](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=5ccb6655-2ff9-4977-bf8b-577e92bbb236), [FTP Server](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=38431c21-1ad8-4825-9a2f-55a4d6a89b87), and [Wi-Fi File Sharer](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=03ddadf3-9406-44b9-8af6-d56d6863100a) on my WP 8.1. All of these worked on **WiFi** and **Internet Sharing** mode as well. It also works when both devices are connected to the **same WiFi**. I tested all these three cases with different combinations (WP to Android, Android to WP and WP to WP).

> ***Conclusion: `ShareIt` and `Zapya` have their own problems.***

Answer (score 1):

ShareIt works only in LAN created by Windows Phone when using Windows Phone.Even when you do WP to ANDROID and vice-versa, WP has to create LAN,else it won't work.

***It is clearly written in manual.***

***Same is with I-Phone.***

***edit*** - It is the restrictions for ShareIt.For other file transfer apps like **Easy File Transfer** being on the **same network** is **enough**.

Comment: How're you going to transfer WP to WP? We'll have to connect both the WPs to same Wi-Fi. Right?

Comment: They should be in same LAN created by Windows Phone.-This is the ShareIt restrictions.

Comment: The phone creating hotspot also becomes part of the LAN. So they are in the same LAN already. You can check the IP addresses. The WP creating hotspot has 192.168.137.1 and the one connecting to the hotspot has 192.168.137.X. Aren't they in the LAN of 2 devices?

Comment: Obviously, they are in LAN in such condition.

Comment: So @unlucky7735. How about your answer?

Comment: @A.B. I have edited my answer.I guess now you won't have any problem with that.

Comment: `ShareIt` works only in LAN created by Windows Phone. Really?